# What is causing my double-submit issue? (been three days now with zero progress)

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, tiles

I'm getting a double-submit issue, and after three days, have still been able to determine the cause.

*(Please note that this is **NOT** the kind caused by the user repeatedly clicking a submit  button and/or refreshing the page.)*

***FWIW***, this double-submit problem is occurring in a much larger application - but, I have cut the code down into much simpler app that still reproduces the issue.

***The users steps to recreate the issue are:***

1. On pageA/ControllerA - user enters a value in the search field (in the left nav bar)
2. The user then chooses from one of three subsequently generated links (i.e., that link to pageB/ControllerB)
3. The user enters text in the pageB and hits the submit button, which passes control back to the pageA.
4. The user clicks the search button again in the left nav bar --- voila (double-submit / browser pop-up)

***Note:***

1. These pages are constructed using [Apache Tiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_view_technologies_and_frameworks#At_a_glance).
2. There is HTML code that is generated for the "left nav bar" - i.e., that happens to be used by both pageA and pageB.

***Thoughts:***
I am wondering if when the users clicks the search button - that button/html that is shared by both pages (i.e, the left nav  bar) is activated for both pages and causing the double-submit.

## Below is the relevant code if you are curious.

#### tiles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
 "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="masterpage" template="/WEB-INF/views/masterlayout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" type="string"/>
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="leftnav" value="/WEB-INF/views/leftnav.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="pageA" extends="masterpage">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="pageA" type="string"/>
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/bodyA.jsp"/>
        <put-list-attribute name="extrastyles">
            <add-attribute value="resources/css/empty.css" type="template"/>
        </put-list-attribute>
        <put-list-attribute name="extrascripts">
            <add-attribute value="resources/js/empty.js" type="template"/>
        </put-list-attribute>
    </definition>

    <definition name="pageB" extends="masterpage">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="pageB" type="string"/>
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/bodyB.jsp"/>
        <put-list-attribute name="extrastyles">
            <add-attribute value="resources/css/empty.css" type="template"/>
        </put-list-attribute>
        <put-list-attribute name="extrascripts">
            <add-attribute value="resources/js/empty.js" type="template"/>
        </put-list-attribute>
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

#### masterlayout.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@taglib prefix="c"      uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="tiles"  uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title><tiles:getAsString name="title" /></title>

            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" />

            <tiles:useAttribute id="styleentries" name="extrastyles" classname="java.util.List" />
            <c:forEach var="s" items="${styleentries}">
                <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/${s}" /><br/>
            </c:forEach>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/main.js"></script>

            <tiles:useAttribute id="scriptentries" name="extrascripts" classname="java.util.List" />
            <c:forEach var="s" items="${scriptentries}">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/${s}"></script><br/>
            </c:forEach>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div style="display: table; min-width: 1000px; min-height: 500px;">
                <div style="display: table-caption; caption-side: top; min-height: 20%; border-style: solid; border-color: black; background-color: lightyellow;">
                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
                </div>
                <div style="display: table-row; height: 60%; min-width:100%;" >
                    <div style="display: table-cell; max-width: 400px; min-height: 100%; border-style: solid; border-color: blue; background-color: lightblue;">
                        <tiles:insertAttribute name="leftnav" />
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: table-cell; min-width: 600px; min-height: 100%; border-style: solid; border-color: green; background-color: lightgray;">
                        <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="display: table-caption; caption-side: bottom;  min-height: 20%; border-style: solid; border-color: black; background-color: lightyellow;">
                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### header.jsp

```
<h1>header</h1>
```

#### leftnav.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<div>
    <h1 id="hdr1">leftnav</h1>
    <c:forEach var="listObj" items="${sharedList}">
        <div>
            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/methodB1.html?parmvalue=${listObj.valuea}">pick ${listObj.valuea}</a>
        </div>
    </c:forEach>
</div>
```

#### bodyA.jsp

```
<div>
    <h1>body-A</h1>
    <h4>entered: ${pojo2.stringA}</h4>
    <h4>${sharedList}</h4>
</div>
```

#### bodyB.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<div>
    <h1>body-B</h1>
    <form:form id="form1" modelAttribute="pojo2" action="methodB2.html" method="post">
        <div>
            <div>
                <form:label path="stringA">StringA value:</form:label>
                </div>
                <div>
                <form:input path="stringA" size="40" maxlength="64" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <h4>picked: ${parmvalue}</h4>
        <h4>${sharedList}</h4>

        <button id="submitbutton">Submit</button>
    </form:form>
</div>
```

#### footer.jsp

```
<h1>footer</h1>
```

#### main.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var jqXHR1 = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'constructSearchBox',
        async: false
    })
    .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        if (data === "good")
        {
            var atdiv = "<div id='at"
                    + Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1)
                    + "'>"
                    + "<label id='atlabel' for='atsearchstring'></label>"
                    + "<input type='search' id='atsearchstring' value=''/><br/>"
                    + "<button id='atsearch' type='button'>Search</button>"
                    + "</div>"
            $("#hdr1").after(atdiv);
        }
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert("FAIL...jqXHR=" + jqXHR + ", textStatus=" + textStatus + ", errorThrown=" + errorThrown);
    });

    $("#atsearch").click(function(e)
    {
        var searchstring = $("#atsearchstring").val();

        var jqXHR2 = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'atSearch',
            data: "searchstring=" + searchstring,
            async: true,
            cache: false
        })
        .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            location.reload(true); //window.location.href = 'atSearch';//window.location = window.location.href;//history.go(0); //
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert("FAIL...(atSearch)...jqXHR=" + jqXHR + ", textStatus=" + textStatus + ", errorThrown=" + errorThrown);
        });
    });

    $('#submitbutton').click(function() {
        $("form1").submit();
    });
});
```

#### ControllerA.java

```
package aaa.bbb.ccc;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@Scope("session")
@SessionAttributes(
    {
    "sharedList"
})
public class ControllerA implements Serializable
{

    @ModelAttribute("sharedList")
    public List<Pojo1> createSharedList()
    {
        return new ArrayList<Pojo1>();
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/pageA", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView pageA(HttpSession session)
    {
        createSharedList();
        return new ModelAndView("pageA");  //...construct every time - just testing...
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/constructSearchBox", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String constructSearchBox(HttpSession session)
    {
        return "good";  //...construct every time - just testing...
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/atSearch", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String atSearch(
        @ModelAttribute("sharedList") List<Pojo1> sharedList,
        @RequestParam(value = "searchstring", required = true) String searchstring,
        HttpSession session,
        Model model)
    {
        if (!String.valueOf(searchstring).equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("lastsearchstring"))))  //...same search string?...
        {
            try
            {
                sharedList.clear();
                sharedList.add(new Pojo1(searchstring + "aaa", searchstring + "bbb", searchstring + "ccc"));
                sharedList.add(new Pojo1(searchstring + "ddd", searchstring + "eee", searchstring + "fff"));
                sharedList.add(new Pojo1(searchstring + "ggg", searchstring + "hhh", searchstring + "iii"));
                session.removeAttribute("lastsearchstring");
                session.setAttribute("lastsearchstring", searchstring);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("ControllerA_________________________atSearch________________________before returning...(saved) searchstring is now:" + String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("lastsearchstring")));
        model.addAttribute("sharedList", sharedList);


        return "pageA";
    }
}
```

#### ControllerB.java

```
package aaa.bbb.ccc;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;

@Controller
@Scope("session")
@SessionAttributes(
    {
    "sharedList"
})
public class ControllerB
{
    public ControllerB()
    {
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/methodB1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView methodB1(
        @RequestParam(value = "parmvalue", required = true) String parmvalue,
        @ModelAttribute("pojo2") Pojo2 pojo2,
        HttpSession session)
    {
        try
        {
            session.setAttribute("parmvalue", parmvalue);
            return new ModelAndView("pageB");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/methodB2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView methodB2(@ModelAttribute("pojo2") Pojo2 pojo2)
    {
        try
        {
            return new ModelAndView("pageA");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

#### Pojo1.java

```
package aaa.bbb.ccc;

public class Pojo1
{
    private String valuea;
    private String valueb;
    private String valuec;


    public Pojo1(String valuea, String valueb, String valuec)
    {
        this.valuea = valuea;
        this.valueb = valueb;
        this.valuec = valuec;
    }

    public String getValuea()
    {
        return valuea;
    }

    public void setValuea(String valuea)
    {
        this.valuea = valuea;
    }

    public String getValueb()
    {
        return valueb;
    }
    public void setValueb(String valueb)
    {
        this.valueb = valueb;
    }

    public String getValuec()
    {
        return valuec;
    }
    public void setValuec(String valuec)
    {
        this.valuec = valuec;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Pojo{" + "valuea=" + valuea + ", valueb=" + valueb + ", valuec=" + valuec + '}';
    }
}
```

#### Pojo2.java

```
package aaa.bbb.ccc;

public class Pojo2
{
    public Pojo2()
    {
        super();
    }

    public Pojo2(String stringA)
    {
        this.stringA = stringA;
    }

    private String stringA;
    public String getStringA()
    {
        return stringA;
    }
    public void setStringA(String stringA)
    {
        this.stringA = stringA;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "FormPojo{" + "stringA=" + stringA + '}';
    }
}
```

#### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>aaa.bbb.ccc</groupId>
    <artifactId>aaatest</artifactId>
    <name>aaatest</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1</version>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Hi - It should be available now.  -I inadvertantly submitted before I was finished. Thx.

Comment: did you have a chance to step through it with debugger?

Comment: I have, but, I did not see anything.  But, I'd appreciate any hint(s) as to what I should be observing, etc.  thx.

Comment: I don't have so much experience in JavaScript, but I would inspect that part first. I would add some console.log or debug point in the browser. Maybe location.reload() could be problematic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem :-**
When user press submit on Page B ,form  gets submitted (browser URL becomes page "methodB2.html" ) and you are returning pageA content in response of that.
Now When user clicks the generated links ,you are reloading the page using below

```
 .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
   {
                location.reload(true);
    })
```

`location.reload` will reload the page by using current url.
In this case it is methodB.html and reload will also submit the form as it was the last action causing your double submit issue.

**Solution:**
To Correct That you can use [Post Redirect Get Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) on submitting form on Page B.
To do that,Modify your `methodB2` handler as

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @RequestMapping(value = "/methodB2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView methodB2(@ModelAttribute("pojo2") Pojo2 pojo2)
        {
           try
           {
              //you may have to change below pageA.jsp to whatever view pageA resolves to 
              //depending upon your viewResolver configuration

                return new ModelAndView("redirect:/pageA.jsp");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou harrybvp for your generous time spent on my question!  I will try this soon on the actual application (of which this was a small model) as well, and let you know what I find.

Comment: Thanks again harrybvp. You solution works on the "model" app I provided. Unfortunately, I cannot get the "redirect" to work on the actual application (http://stackoverflow.com/q/18023965/652078). -I provided a link, in case you might have time to help.